# How to remove Elements using iMacros?

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I want to display only the elements that are needed

my code is not working

```
     remove();
     function remove() {
     var target = window.document.querySelectorAll('a[href="/*-i.*.*?position=*"]');
     target.forEach(function(anchors) {
     anchors.parentNode.remove();
     })
     }
```

I want to display the URL below only

[Url](https://shopee.co.id/*?ads_keyword=*ads%20...%20&position=*)

or I want to display a product that says "Iklan"

below is the website in question
[website](https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=sepatu)

any idea ?

```
Browser Firefox 48.0
iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7
Windows 10 32-bit Operating system
```

Comment: instead of removing them could you just set them to `element.style.display = "none"`

Comment: I'm a beginner
I still can't do it